# Display data attributes in collection field Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have 2 fields in my form. First Name and Email.

```
$builder->add('firstName', 'text', [
                 'label' => 'First Name',
                 'required' => true,
                 'attr' => [
                     'data-msg-required' => 'First name is required'
                 ],
                 'trim' => true])
        ->add('emails', 'collection', [
                'type'         => new RegisterEmail,
                'required'     => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'label'        => false,
                'options' => [
                    'attr' => [
                        'data-msg-required' => 'Email is required'
                    ]
                ],
            ]);
```

However data-msg required is only displayed for first field but not for second one. I know I can add that directly in twig template but is there anyway I can achieve that through form class only.

Answer (score 0):

You should add it to the default value of the RegisterEmail type, with setDefaults()